# .htaccess remove subdirectory from URL

Tags: .htaccess, subdirectory

I can't seem to figure this out, I have a directory structure in my root folder like '/state/page--city'. In my htaccess file i redirect all requests that are not directories or files in my root folder to a page.php. So what I would want is to remove the '/state' part from the URL when the users access 'http://example.com/state/page--city/' so that the URL looks like 'http://example.com/page--city/'. Any ideas? Thnx.

.htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l


RewriteRule .* page.php?&[|]v1||%{REQUEST_URI}[|]v2||-[|]v3||%{HTTP_HOST}[|]v4||%{REQUEST_FILENAME}[|]v5||EOL[~|~]= [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Could you post the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: you want it to display `'http://page--city'` skipping your domain name?

Comment: sorry about that ... with the domain name...I corrected the post